# How to handle data loss in Redis Pub/Sub when using socket connection?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, publish-subscribe, spring-websocket, spring-data-redis

I have a Spring Boot application that uses Redis Pub/Sub to publish data from one service to another service, which then sends the data to a driver app using a socket connection. The problem is that Redis Pub/Sub doesn't have an ACK mechanism, so if the socket connection is broken, the data will be lost.

I'm looking for a workaround to handle this situation. Ideally, I would like to:

- Ensure that the data is not lost if the socket connection is broken.
- Retry sending the data when the connection is restored.

I'm wondering if there's a simpler solution that can be implemented within the Spring Boot application by only using Redis Pub/Sub.

Can someone suggest a way to handle this scenario? Any code examples or tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!